# Laravel route removing parent route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I have a laravel project which I am working on, the public folder of the laravel project is in a sub folder
i.e. htdocs/laravel_folder/public_folder and files
so in the web browser the address is `www.website.com/laravel_folder/laravel_page_etc`
I have been able to load the index file but when i want to load another file it removes the parent folder(i.e. laravel_folder)
so the uri become
`www.website.com/page_to_be_loaded` instead of `www.website.com/laravel_folder/page_to_be_loaded`

This is my controller

```
public function load_form(Request $request) {
    //return view('blade_file_to_load');// I have tried this
    return redirect()
    ->route('route_to_load')
    ->guest('blade_file_to_load');//i tried this one also
        
}
```

this is the web.php

```
Route::get('/', 'MyController@index'); //this one show the index page when i load "laravel_folder"
Route::get('/form_load', 'MyController@load_form');
Route::post('/form_load', 'MyController@insert_record');
```

Basically when i try to load `"laravel_folder/form_load"` it would show in the browser address bar `"form_load"` and page not found

**Update:** But when i try the following route

1. 'www.website.com/laravel_folder/page_to_be_loaded' it tries to load the index page, and this produces an error because the page is expecting a data which is not presented to it
2. [www.website.com/laravel_folder/page_to_be_loaded](http://www.website.com/laravel_folder/page_to_be_loaded) **/** with the **/** added to the end of it it would remove the **laravel_folder** as I stated earlier.

**Update 2** I changed the .env variable of APP_URL localhost to http:// [www.website.com/folder_name](http://www.website.com/folder_name) but it is still doing the same thing

Comment: you need a lot of tweeks, here is a tutorial https://medium.com/@lucabecchetti/configure-laravel-to-work-in-a-subdirectory-and-with-artisan-serve-at-the-same-time-654ba0c1fd0b

Comment: What is `APP_URL` set to in your `.env` file?

Comment: @kerbh0lz, I have set the app_url to default to the sub directory route but it is still doing the same thing.

Comment: can you try printing ``{{ env('APP_URL') }} in any view and check what does it prints?

Comment: @OMiShah please how can i would i put it inside the view i.e. return view('view_name') ?

Comment: just call that code in your ``view.blade.php`` file

Comment: @OMiShah I have added it to it but it is showing me http:// localhost/folder_name and not http:// www.website.com/folder_name. I put space there so that it can show the http://

Comment: and what does your ``.env`` file has value for ``APP_URL``?

Comment: @OMiShah .env has APP_URL has http:// localhost. should the APP_URL had been http:// www.website.com/folder_name?

Comment: I have changed from localhost to online url it did not make any change

Comment: @N69S I have followed the the link and read it but there was no change to the problem

Comment: run ``php artisan config:clear`` and ``php artisan cache:clear`` in your project and try.

Comment: I am using a shared host i dont have access to shell